# What software (SAAS) is available to manage SOA?

Tags: architecture, documentation, project-management, soa

We have about 15 services and need a way to manage various pieces of information.

1. State of each service - when was it deployed? Which commit?
2. Some services share the same database - Which service uses which database?
3. Managing the state of each database - Which migrations have been run? What tables and fields are present?
4. Managing different environments for each service and database. There are Dev, QA and Production environments.
5. Tracking dependencies. A migration file may be committed into one service's repo, the database might be migrated at some point in the future, and another service needs to be deployed with an update.
6. Build status. It would be nice to see if the last commit for certain branches have all the tests passing. Maybe this could be a badge from a CI service.

What software is available to do this? Looking for a browser based hosted solution.

Comment: What is technology behind services?

Comment: Git, Rack, Rails and Postgres.

Comment: Than my answer will be helpful for you, since they use those tools or are designed for them at first place.u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a tool like `Jenkins`. [Link](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

> **Jenkins** is an open source continuous integration tool written in Java. The project was forked from Hudson after a dispute with Oracle.
>
> Jenkins can be used with different technologies, (JAVA, .NET, Rails etc.)

On the other hand tool that can help you manage Dev/QA/Production environments is Artifactory.  [Link](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti)

Here is a nice tutorial for combining Jenkins and `Artifactory`. [Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)

This solution (`Jenikns`+`Artfactory`) can be used for tracking build numbers/versions, binaries and databases deployment(s), triggered build(on checkin/on merge/on push), automatically starting tests (unit/integration), propagation of deployment packages from one to another environment.